# Java best practice for sleep?

Tags: java, sleep

Background: I've been habitually converting `Thread.sleep()` calls to `TimeUnit.XXX.sleep()` calls, whenever I need to otherwise touch code containing that.

Questions: First of all, is this ok, or is there some subtle problem with TimeUnit's sleep? Then, as far as I've figured out, this is best way to wait before a network (or similar) operation retry like

```
for(int retriesLeft = 3; ;--retriesleft) {
    try {
        doOperation(...);
        break;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        if (retryCountDown <= 0) throw ex;
        else TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Is `TimeUnit.XXXX.sleep(10)` the right way to sleep above, or is there a better way? Also, feel free to comment if there's a better Java pattern to handle the whole network operation retry logic...

Comment: Belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can questions be moved between stackexchange sites?

Comment: yes, if you want your question to get moved, just flag it so that some moderator can do that for you.

Comment: Should not use exceptions to control flow!

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon That's not control flow, that's an error plain and simple, as wrapper should work identically to just calling doOperation once. It's still slightly bad in the way it loses retried errors, which may have been different, and only re-throws the last exception, but OTOH the last network error is most likely to be accurate in current situation.

Comment: @hyde - Then the loop should be `for(...) { if ( doOperation() == success ) break;}` and `doOperation` should have the `try {} catch() {return failed;}`

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Exceptions, especially checked ones, are perfect for this sort of thing. The API you propose is very limiting: a) you lose the return-value communication channel (or at least make it overly complex) b) you force immediate handling of failure. Finally, if you think **retrying** does not belong into the **failure recovery** department, then what on Earth does belong there?

Comment: It is my opinion that if there is a clear option for `doOperation()` to fail then a failure indicator should be constructed in `doOperation()` not outside it. It is wrong to use the exception itself as a failure indicator. Is failure an exception or not?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Your description quite precisely matches the use case for checked exceptions: **exceptional, but expected** events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thread.sleep() only accepts time in milliseconds.Therefore a helper class was introduced TimeUnit which would specify the units like SEC, HOURs which is much more convenient thn inputting milliseconds. It helps in increasing the readability of the code also.

check the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html

Comment: There is a version of Thread#sleep that takes nanoseconds too: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long,%20int%29

Comment: Thanks for correcting.. never used nanoseconds..so missed it.

Answer (score 3):

[TimeUnit#sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#sleep%28long%29) is "a convenience method that converts time arguments into the form required by the Thread.sleep method." So it does not do anything different than your old code.